# Group Homomorphism: Implications of identical kernels on homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If f and g are two **epimorphisms** of a group G onto a group H such that ***ker f* = *ker g***, then **is** ***f = g* necessarily**?

(I can think of disproving it by taking the specific case of **kernel being null** so that homomorphism becomes **one-one**, is the approach correct? 
Can this be disproven **without a particular example**? 
P.S.: I don't know the answer)

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=H$ and take $f$ and $g$ automorphisms of $G$. Then clearly $\ker(f)=\ker(g)=1$, the trivial group, however not $f=g$ in general. For example, consider the automorphism group of $S_3$. It has $6$ elements.

[Proving that Aut($S_3$) is isomorphic to $S_3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773154/proving-that-auts-3-is-isomorphic-to-s-3?rq=1)

[Finding the automorphisms of $S_3$ by looking at the orders of the elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538681/finding-the-automorphisms-of-s-3-by-looking-at-the-orders-of-the-elements/1538786)

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is right, and there's no way to disprove this without a specific example.

To use your idea, you can compare the identity map to a nontrivial automorphism on $G$, which are obviously not equal but have the same kernel. You still have to exhibit this automorphism though, because you need to produce a specific counterexample to disprove this.