# Number of homomorphisms $f:S_3 \to S_3$ when $\ker(f)=(1)$.

Tags: group-theory

I am finding the number of homomorphisms $f:S_3 \to S_3$ when $\ker(f)=(1)$.

By first isomorphism theorem, $$S_3/Ker(f)=S_3/(1) \simeq f(S_3)\subset S_3.$$i.e, $f:S_3 \to S_3$in this case. Now any element $x \in S_3$ goes to $f(x) \in f(S_3)=S_3$.  Also $O(f(x)) |O(x)$.

The $identity$ permutation  $(1)$ maps to $(1)$ as $1|1$;

order $2$ elements maps to order $2$ elements, i.,e., $\{(12),(13),(23) \} \to \{(12),(13),(23) \}$ in $3!=6$ ways.

**But the problem occurs** with the order $3$ elements, $(132)$ and $(123)$.

We can have $f((123))=(123)$ or $f((123))=(132)$  and $f((132))=(132)$ or $f((132))=(132)$.

So here total $2!$ ways.

Hence total $6 \times 2=12$ homomorphisms  from $S_3 \to S_3$  if $\ker(f)=(1)$.

Is it true?

**Edit:**  Why  we cannot get $f((123))=(132)$ or $f((132))=(123)$ ?

Comment: Do you seek the number of automorphisms of $S_3$?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1538681/finding-the-automorphisms-of-s-3-by-looking-at-the-orders-of-the-elements); once you determine where the $2$-cycles are mapped, doesn't that determine where the $3$-cycles are mapped, since the $3$-cycles are products of $2$-cycles?

Comment: Or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773154/proving-that-auts-3-is-isomorphic-to-s-3).

Comment: @J.W.Tanner,  Suppose $f(12)=(13)$ and $f(13)=(12)$,then $f(123)=f((13)(12))=f((13)(12))=(12)(13)=(132)$. Where is the error ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR:  You said in OP we can have $f((123))=(123) $ or $(132)$, but I'm saying that once you have determined which one of the six ways $(12), (13)$, and $(23)$ are mapped by $f$, then there is only one possible result for $f((123))$, namely $f((13))f((12))$, which has already been determined

Comment: @J.W.Tanner,  there is subtle point which is making me confused. You said by homomorphism $f(123)$ is determined by $f(13)f(12)$. Now we have included the possibility  $f(13)=(12)$ and $f(13)=(12)$ in the order $2$ case. So $f(123)=f(13)f(12)=(12)(13)=(132)$.  I can not catch the error here .

Comment: I'm saying that if you have determined that $f((13))=(12)$ and $f((12))=(13)$, then you have determined $f((123))$ -- i.e., there is only one possibility for $f((123))$, not two

Comment: @J.W.Tanner,that means if we have $f(132)=(123)$,then we can not have $f(132)=(132)$ and vice-versa

Comment: some of the homomorphisms will map $(132)$ to $(123)$ and some will map to $(132)$ to $(132)$, but, again, once you have determined where a homomorphism maps the $2$-cycles, you won't have a choice as to where it maps the $3$-cycles, if it's a bona fide homomorphism

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, thanks  for nice help.I got it finally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are seeking the automorphisms of $S_3$

(homomorphisms from $S_3$ to itself with trivial kernel).

It is not true that there are $12$ of them; there are only $6$ of them.

That is because there are $6$ possible ways that the $2$-cycles could be mapped, as you pointed out,

and, once those are determined, there is only one possible way the $3$-cycles

(which are products of $2$-cycles) could be mapped.

Answer (score 1):

By finiteness, such a map would be an automorphism.  The set of automorphisms of $S_n,n\ne2,6$ is $S_n$.  The natural map induces an isomorphism.