# Is an automorphism a function or a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

this is my first time on the Stack Exchange so I apologize if I went about asking this improperly! I was working on a problem set that asked to compute Aut(S3). In class we've been thinking about automorphisms as a function that maps elements of one group to another. However it seems like an automorphism can be better thought of as a subgroup of S3. Could someone provide clarity about what it means to compute/find Aut(S3)?

Comment: Automorphism is a function from the group to itself that respects the operation. Do you have a representation for $S_3$? Probably that helps.

Comment: Can you explain how you think an automorphism could be thought of as a subgroup? I think that will help you get an answer that clears up your misunderstanding.

Comment: The automorphisms of a group $G$ are particular (group's operation preserving) bijections on $G$, so the only you may hope -in terms of subgroups- is that $\operatorname{Aut}(G)\le  \operatorname{Sym}(G)$ (which is indeed the case).

Comment: @MatthewTowers I think an automorphism is a bijective isomorphism from a group to itself. So when asking for Aut(S3) it's asking for the group containing all bijective isomorphisms of S3. Is my understanding now correct?

Comment: Specifically for $\operatorname{Aut}(S_3)$, see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1538681/810157

Comment: The phrase "thinking about automorphisms as a function" doesn't read well and perhaps illustrates an issue you have. The phrase mixes "automorphisms" (plural) and "function" (singular). The correct form is: automorphisms (plural) are functions (plural), and they form a group. An automorphism (singular) is a function (singular), and it does not in general form a group.

Answer (score 9):

The automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut} S_3$ is the *group of automorphisms* on $S_3$. So it’s a group, but its elements are automorphisms of $S_3$,

$$\operatorname{Aut} S_3 = \{σ \colon S_3 → S_3;~σ~\text{is a group automorphism} \}.$$

Keep in mind that *automorphisms* are meant to be maps from a group *to itself* – and **not** to another group. It stems from the greek word [αὐτóς](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek), meaning “self” or “same”, so its something that shapes (grk. “[μορφóω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%81%CF%86%CF%8C%CF%89#Ancient_Greek)”) the group into *itself*, the *same* group.  Automobiles are things that *movable* (lat. “[mobilis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mobilis)”) *by themselves*. Most terms in mathematics actually have meaning.

Comment: Also it’s not too hard to prove that for any group $G$, Aut($G$) is a group under function composition. The identity is the automorphism that maps all elements in $G$ to themselves; automorphisms are isomorphisms, hence they’re bijective and invertible, hence every element has an inverse; function composition is associative. Done.

Answer (score 5):

I think   this

> In class we've been thinking about automorphisms as a function that
> maps elements of one group to another.

is not quite right. *Homomorphisms* are functions that map the elements of one group to another (and preserve the group multiplication).

When the domain and codomain of a homomorphism are the same group and the homomorphism is bijective (so an isomorphism) then you call that homomorphism an *automorphism*.

If you have a group $G$ (say, $S_3$) then you can consider all the automorphisms of that group. The set of those automorphisms is itself a group (under functional composition) called the automorphism group of $G$.

You have been asked to find that group - start by listing its elements.

.